# Capitalization API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any good API or service that handles capitalization well? It should be able to handle input like "i need help fixing my iphone asap" with a desired output of "I Need Help Fixing My iPhone ASAP".

Edit: This is in conjunction with titleize. Titleize doesn't handle words like "iPhone" and acronyms. I'm currently getting user input like "ceo" and titleize returns "Ceo", when I'd like "CEO". I'd prefer not to write a list of special capitalizations, especially if there is a good alternative.

Another alternative would be a library of words and the correct capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`#titleize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) in `ActiveSupport::Inflector`

Answer (score 0):

```
"man from the boondocks".titleize   # => "Man From The Boondocks"
"x-men: the last stand".titleize    # => "X Men: The Last Stand"
"TheManWithoutAPast".titleize       # => "The Man Without A Past"
"raiders_of_the_lost_ark".titleize  # => "Raiders Of The Lost Ark"
```

Cut and paste from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize